# Conditional rendering react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, render

I need to apply a css class once to the LilCard component but not on the BigCard component. I do need to rendering them in the same map function so, I can't find a way to apply the "problem" class only to LilCard.

```
        {results.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div className="problem"> <--- Here
              {item.map((subitem, i) => {
                if (i !== 0) {
                  return <LilCard article={subitem} />;
                } else {
                  return <BigCard article={subitem} />;
                }
              })}
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

The html is looking like this, i want BigCard to be wrapped with "col-lg-6 mb-5 mb-lg-0" class and LilCard to be wrapped in "col-lg-6 pl-lg-4" class.

```
         <div class="row">
             <div class="col-lg-6 mb-5 mb-lg-0">
                 <div class="entry2">
                     <a href="single.html"><img src="images/img_1.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid rounded"></a>
                     <span class="post-category text-white bg-success mb-3">Nature</span>
                     <h2><a href="single.html">The 20 Biggest Fintech Companies In America 2019</a></h2>
                     <div class="post-meta align-items-center text-left clearfix">
                         <figure class="author-figure mb-0 mr-3 float-left"><img src="images/person_1.jpg"
                                 alt="Image" class="img-fluid"></figure>
                         <span class="d-inline-block mt-1">By <a href="#">Carrol Atkinson</a></span>
                         <span>&nbsp;-&nbsp; February 10, 2019</span>
                     </div>
                     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo sunt tempora dolor laudantium
                         sed optio, explicabo ad deleniti impedit facilis fugit recusandae! Illo, aliquid, dicta
                         beatae quia porro id est.</p>
                 </div>
             </div>
             <div class="col-lg-6 pl-lg-4">
                 <div class="entry3 d-block d-sm-flex">
                     <figure class="figure order-2"><a href="single.html"><img src="images/img_2.jpg" alt="Image"
                                 class="img-fluid rounded"></a></figure>
                     <div class="text mr-4 order-1">
                         <span class="post-category text-white bg-success mb-3">Nature</span>
                         <h2><a href="single.html">The 20 Biggest Fintech Companies In America 2019</a></h2>
                         <span class="post-meta mb-3 d-block">May 12, 2019</span>
                         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo sunt tempora dolor
                             laudantium sed optio.</p>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="entry3 d-block d-sm-flex">
                     <figure class="figure order-2"><a href="single.html"><img src="images/img_3.jpg" alt="Image"
                                 class="img-fluid rounded"></a></figure>
                     <div class="text mr-4 order-1">
                         <span class="post-category text-white bg-success mb-3">Nature</span>
                         <h2><a href="single.html">The 20 Biggest Fintech Companies In America 2019</a></h2>
                         <span class="post-meta mb-3 d-block">May 12, 2019</span>
                         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo sunt tempora dolor
                             laudantium sed optio.</p>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="entry3 d-block d-sm-flex">
                     <figure class="figure order-2"><a href="single.html"><img src="images/img_4.jpg" alt="Image"
                                 class="img-fluid rounded"></a></figure>
                     <div class="text mr-4 order-1">
                         <span class="post-category text-white bg-success mb-3">Nature</span>
                         <h2><a href="single.html">The 20 Biggest Fintech Companies In America 2019</a></h2>
                         <span class="post-meta mb-3 d-block">May 12, 2019</span>
                         <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo sunt tempora dolor
                             laudantium sed optio.</p>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want to show first items in your subarrays as `BigCard` and other's to be `LilCard` Component( Update From comments section.

I have updated my code to get that behavior.

**CODESANDBOX LINK:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/life-is-a-challenge-42vjj

**WORKING CODE SNIPPET:**

```js
const App = ()=>{
  const articles = [
    [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "test"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "test2"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        title: "coucou"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        id: 1,
        title: "ekip"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: "bjr"
      }
    ]
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {articles.map((array) => {
        return array.map(({ id, title }) => {
          const item =
            id === 1 ? <BigCard title={title} /> : <LilCard title={title} />;
          return item;
        });
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

const BigCard = ({title}) => {
  return <article className="bigCard">I am a Big Card :  {title}</article>;
};

const LilCard = ({title}) => {
  return <article className="lilCard">I am a little Card {title}</article>;
};



ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.lilCard {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

.bigCard {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: orange;
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thx dude ! i tried it but it apply the class to every LilCard generated by the map and here i want all the lilcard generated to be wrapped in this class

Comment: Hmmm, I see. I actually didn't get it fully yet. Could you create a codesandbox projects and share the link so that we get more idea about what is going on.

Comment: yup : https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-rgb-7f9yw, i don't really know how to explain clearly but i put some html on my first post if it can help

Comment: yes i have an array with different arrays in it, i want the first item of each arrays to be a BigCard, the others are lilcard

Answer (score 0):

```
{results.map((item) => {
          return (
            <div> <--- Here
              {item.map((subitem, i) => {
                if (i !== 0) {
                  return <LilCard article={subitem className="problem"} />;
                } else {
                  return <BigCard article={subitem} />;
                }
              })}
            </div>
          );
        })}
```

I think this is what you need

or

```
{results.map((item) => {
              return (
                  {item.map((subitem, i) => {
                    if (i !== 0) {
                       <div className="problem">
                                <LilCard article={subitem }
                             </div> />;
                    } else {
                       <div> 
                               <BigCard article={subitem} />
                            </div>;
                    }
                  })}
              );
            })}
```

Comment: he wanted the class to be applied to the **wrapper** of LilCard

Comment: i need the class to be outside the second map so she's called just once

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 {results.map((item) => {
              return (
                   <>
                  {item.map((subitem, i) => {
                    if (i !== 0) {
                      return <div className="problem"><LilCard article={subitem} /></div>;
                    } else {
                      return <div><BigCard article={subitem} /></div>;
                    }
                  })}
              </>
              );
            })}
```

**EDIT**
check the new answer as after your explanations in the comments:

```
const orderCards = () => {

    const lilcards = [];
    const bigcards = [];

    {
        results.map((item) => {
            {
                item.map((subitem, i) => {
                    if (i !== 0)
                        lilcards.push(<LilCard article={subitem} />)
                    else
                        bigcards.push(<BigCard article={subitem} />)
                })
            }
        })
    }

    return(
        <>
        <div className="problem">{lilcards.map(lilcard=>{return lilcard})}</div>
        <div >{bigcards.map(bigcard=>{return bigcard})}</div>
        </>
    );

}
```

Can you see what I did here?

Comment: yes but i need the class to be outside the second map so she's called just once

Comment: i==0 only once my friend

Comment: it apply the class to every LilCard generated by the map and here i want all the lilcard generated to be wrapped in this class, i put some more code for more understanding

Comment: but you map every `item` with a `return` method so you cannot wrap seperated-returned elements. Only in the parent that get the returned values. Is that a must? because I have different method. I'll post it as an answer in couple of minutes

Comment: check the new answer. I made a method to order all the cards like you want. you can send `results` as a parameter to that function if you want or embed the function in your old one somehow

Comment: yes! that is nearly it except that it should render 1 bigcard then 3 lilcard then 1 bigcard then 3 lilcard etc. (there is 4 card by array) but thanks dude i will make it i guess with your solution.